# Get previous row value based on a timestamp for matching IDs

Tags: azure-sql-database, databricks, databricks-sql

I have a table about shipping that has information about the arrival (country and date) to a port. Now I need to extract the country where it departed from using the previous row entries. The table looks like this

| ID | CountryArrival | DateArrival |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BE | 1-1-2022 |
| 2 | US | 1-1-2022 |
| 1 | NL | 2-1-2022 |
| 2 | IT | 4-1-2022 |
| 1 | PT | 5-1-2022 |

I want to obtain the departure for each ID based on the previous ArrivalDate so it would look like this

| ID | CountryArrival | DateArrival | DeparturePort |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BE | 1-1-2022 | NULL |
| 2 | US | 1-1-2022 | NULL |
| 1 | NL | 2-1-2022 | BE |
| 2 | IT | 4-1-2022 | US |
| 1 | PT | 5-1-2022 | NL |

I can obtain the previous Country based only on DateArrival with:

```
select 
 pc.*,
    lag(pc.CountryArrival) over (order by DateArrival) as DeparturePort
from shipping pc
where pc.DateArrival is not null;
```

Any idea how to get the previous arrival for matching IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `PARTITION BY` the `ID` column.

```
 lag(pc.CountryArrival) over (PARTITION BY ID order by DateArrival) as DeparturePort
```

Comment: Hi. This works perfectly! Quick aside as this wan't the question but is there a more efficient way of doing this without having to sort the date?